# How to add the + sign before a phone number flutter project

Tags: flutter, dart

The flutter project can't add the + sign in front of the phone number

```
onPressed: () async {
                                  if (await canLaunch(
                                      'tel://${widget.provider.itemDetail.data.user.userPhone}') {
                                    await launch(
                                        'tel://${widget.provider.itemDetail.data.user.userPhone}')
                                  } else {
                                    throw 'Could not Call Phone';
                                  }
                                },
```

No error, the problem is that the real device does not display a + sign and without the + sign can not make a call, in the emulator android studio all works fine. The real device samsung A50

```
pubspec.yaml 
url_launcher: 5.5.2

import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

 build.gradle 

     android {
       compileSdkVersion 29

       minSdkVersion 21
            targetSdkVersion 29
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Do you get any error message? If so, please add it to your question. Any other undesired behavior? Please describe it in detail. Please add enough detail so that people can reproduce your problem with only the code or details in your question.

Comment: No error, the problem is that the real device does not display a + sign and without the + sign can not make a call, in the emulator android studio all works fine

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should be able to check if the first character of your phone number is the '+' symbol:

```
String phoneNumber = widget.provider.itemDetail.data.user.userPhone;

if(phoneNumber.substring(0,1) == '+'){
      // Call the number
    } else {
    phoneNumber = '+' + phoneNumber;
      // Then call the number
  }
```

Additionally, if you want to display the '+' sign in front of the phone number in the UI, you can use the [mask_text_input_formatter](https://pub.dev/packages/mask_text_input_formatter) package. Create a phone number mask (eg. +1 (xxx) xxx-xxxx) and add it as an inputFormatter.